# Prevent indenting of multi-line comma-separated assignment

Tags: c, clang-format

In a list of comma-separated statements containing at least 1 assignment, clang-format indents every subsequent statement (assignment or not) relatively to the last assignment. How can I prevent it from doing it without reordering the statements?
Example: (`->` are tabs and `.` are spaces):
Prevent this

```
if ( v[ i ] - '0' == z )
->  a--,
->  v[ i++ ] = -1,
->  ->  ...--b,
->  ->  ...c++;
```

and make it do this:

```
if ( v[ i ] - '0' == z )
->  a--,
->  v[ i++ ] = -1,
->  --b,
->  c++;
```

I tried changing align, binpack and indent options, but to no success.
Here's my .clang-format file

```
---
Language:        Cpp
# BasedOnStyle:  LLVM
AccessModifierOffset: -2
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: false
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: true
AlignEscapedNewlines: Left
AlignOperands:   true
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: None
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: true
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BraceWrapping:
  AfterClass:      false
  AfterControlStatement: true
  AfterEnum:       true
  AfterFunction:   true
  AfterNamespace:  true
  AfterObjCDeclaration: false
  AfterStruct:     true
  AfterUnion:      true
  AfterExternBlock: true
  BeforeCatch:     true
  BeforeElse:      true
  IndentBraces:    false
  SplitEmptyFunction: false
  SplitEmptyRecord: false
  SplitEmptyNamespace: false
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
BreakBeforeInheritanceComma: false
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: false
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: false
BreakConstructorInitializers: AfterColon
BreakAfterJavaFieldAnnotations: false
BreakStringLiterals: false
ColumnLimit:    0
CommentPragmas:  '^ IWYU pragma:'
CompactNamespaces: false
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: true
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
ContinuationIndentWidth: 0
Cpp11BracedListStyle: false
DerivePointerAlignment: false
DisableFormat:   false
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
FixNamespaceComments: true
ForEachMacros:
  - foreach
  - Q_FOREACH
  - BOOST_FOREACH
IncludeBlocks:   Regroup
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex:           '^"(llvm|llvm-c|clang|clang-c)/'
    Priority:        2
  - Regex:           '^(<|"(gtest|gmock|isl|json)/)'
    Priority:        3
  - Regex:           '.*'
    Priority:        1
IncludeIsMainRegex: '$'
IndentCaseLabels: true
IndentPPDirectives: AfterHash
IndentWidth:     4
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: true
JavaScriptQuotes: Leave
JavaScriptWrapImports: true
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
MacroBlockBegin: ''
MacroBlockEnd:   ''
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: None
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 2
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: false
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: true
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 2
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 19
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000000
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 1000000
PointerAlignment: Middle
RawStringFormats:
  - Delimiter:       pb
    Language:        TextProto
    BasedOnStyle:    google
ReflowComments:  true
SortIncludes:    true
SortUsingDeclarations: true
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: true
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 8
SpacesInAngles:  true
SpacesInContainerLiterals: true
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: true
SpacesInParentheses: true
SpacesInSquareBrackets: true
Standard:        Auto
TabWidth:        4
UseTab:          Always
...
```

Comment: Why are these comma separated? Use semi-colon. There's no need I can see to separate these by commas. That's something that's technically allowed but is intended for situations where there's no alternative, like inside a `for` loop.

Comment: I really don't think this is very clear code, but it apparently is valid.  I still suspect that the clang-formatter won't provide an option for the setting you want, since this is such an unusual way to use the comma operator.

Comment: @Claies Seems to be the case. VS formatter doesn't do this, though.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a defect in `clang-format`, and it's a strange one.

The problem appears to your setting `SpacesInSquareBrackets: true`, combined with the use of the comma operator, and having an assignment, and the assignment must involve square brackets on the left side, and the array index must use pre- or post-increment. In addition, any comma-separated clauses before the assignment must involve pre- or post-increment. Very strange.

Of course, using the comma operator like this is unusual and would not be considered good style. If you really must use the comma operator like that, then you'll need to set `SpacesInSquareBrackets: false`.

Using the [configurator](https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/), I verified that this is present on both 6.0.0 and 10.0.0, so it has been there awhile.